# Can only use -performBlock: on an NSManagedObjectContext that was created with a queue

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, core-data, grand-central-dispatch

I want to use multithreading with Core Data. I parse xml-file in `NSManageObject`s. I use the code below and I get runtime error `Can only use -performBlock: on an NSManagedObjectContext that was created with a queue`. What's wrong?

```
//xmlParser

- (void)main
{
    dispatch_queue_t queueB = dispatch_queue_create("Create Books", NULL);
    dispatch_async(queueB, ^{
        // Opening xml
        // ...
        NSManagedObjectContext* context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [context setPersistentStoreCoordinator:mainContext].persistentStoreCoordinator];
        [context performBlock:^{
             // ...
             [self _parseNode:container_node appendTo:books inContext:context];
             // ...
             NSError* error = nil;
             [context save:&error];
             [mainContext performBlock:^{
                 NSError* parentError = nil;
                 [mainContext save:&parentError];
             }];
         }];
         [context release];
     });
     dispatch_release(queueB);
}

- (int)_parseNode:(axlNode*)inode appendTo:(NSMutableArray*)ioarray inContext:(NSManagedObjectContext*)context
{
    // ...
    [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`performBlock` can only be used with a managed object context (MOC) of the `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` or
`NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType`. In your case, you should create the context with

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc]
                     initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
```

And there is no need to create a dispatch queue or use `dispatch_async()`.
 The MOC creates and manages its own queues,
and `performBlock` ensures that the block is executed on the MOC's queue.

Comment: If only the documentation wasn't so vague on this point... I was still wrapping initWithConcurrencyType: up in a dispatch block and creating a custom queue as the documentation hinted that you had to do so... Thanks!

Comment: @RobGlassey: Unfortunately, the "Core Data Programming Guide" has not yet been updated for the new concurrency types, it is documented only in the ["Core Data Release Notes for OS X v10.7 and iOS 5.0"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/DataManagement/RN-CoreData/index.html).

Comment: Aha, there it is! Clear as day. Still, iOS 5 hasn't been out that long really... they'll probably move essential titbits like this into the main reference guides before too long.